# Google map API Term of Service

Tags: android, google-maps, licensing

I'm developing an app which used google map API. Some feature of app are In-app purchases. 
I've read [ToS](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_9_1), in 9.1.2

> 9.1.2 Exceptions.
>
> (a) Enterprise Agreement with Google. The rules in Section 9.1.1 (Free
>   Access, Public Access) do not apply if you have entered into a
>   separate written agreement with Google (such as a Google Enterprise
>   agreement) or obtained Google's written permission.
>
> (b) Mobile Applications. (i) The rule in Section 9.1.1(a) (Free
>   Access) does not apply if your Maps API Implementation is used in a
>   mobile application that is sold for a fee through an online store and
>   is downloadable to a mobile device that can access the online store.
>
> (ii) The rule in Section 9.1.1(b) (Public Access) does not apply if
>   your Maps API Implementation is an Android application that uses the
>   Google Maps Android API. (However, the rule in Section 9.1.1(b)
>   (Public Access) will continue to apply if your Maps API Implementation
>   is an Android application that uses any other Maps APIs, unless the
>   Maps API Implementation qualifies for the exception in Section
>   9.1.2(a) (Enterprise Agreement with Google).)

it means my app must be 100% free??.

I have 2 question now:

1. My app provide map view are free and some of other feature have fee, is this possible?
2. I'll use google map API but Geocoding from another provider. Is that ok?

Comment: StackOverflow is really for programming questions, not for discussions about Terms Of Service

Comment: @duncan tks, I'm new in StackOverflow so I don't know this.

Comment: @duncan but why post like this exists ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746153/google-maps-api-licence?rq=1

Comment: IMHO that question should have been closed too

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140561/are-terms-of-service-questions-okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the FAQ:

> Can I use the Google Maps API on a commercial website? As long as your
>   site is generally accessible to consumers without charge, you may use
>   the Google Maps API. For example, if your website is supported by
>   advertising, it likely falls within the Google Maps API Terms of
>   Service. If you charge people to place information on your map (e.g.
>   to list their homes for sale), but you display this information using
>   the Google Maps API on a free part of your site, you'll also meet the
>   Google Maps API Terms of Service.
>
> However, not all commercial uses are allowed. For example, if your
>   site meets any of the following criteria you must purchase the
>   appropriate Google Maps API for Business license:
>
> Your site is only available to paying customers. Your site is only
>   accessible within your company or on your intranet. Your application
>   relates to enterprise dispatch, fleet management, business asset
>   tracking, or similar applications. Remember, Google reserves the right
>   to suspend or terminate your use of the Google Maps API at any time,
>   so please ensure that you read the Terms of Service carefully.

And from exceptions:

> (b) Mobile Applications. (i) The rule in Section 9.1.1(a) (Free
>   Access) does not apply if your Maps API Implementation is used in a
>   mobile application that is sold for a fee through an online store and
>   is downloadable to a mobile device that can access the online store.

The way I read this is that you may use the API for commercial purposes if you develop for an app sold for a fee. I highly doubt that any of this applies to in-app purchases, which Google does not explicitly reference.

**PLEASE NOTE however that NONE of us will be able to give you legal advice. The Google team will not give you any legal advice either. You NEED to consult with a lawyer for full legal advice.**

Comment: Because my english is not good so i ask for some advice. This is lawyer's work. But i don't have a lawyer, I only need advice to continue development my app :)